# How to model real-world apps with NgRx and different lazy-loaded Angular modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ngrx

I'm new to Angular/NgRx and I'm having troubles understanding the relationship between NgRx features and Angular modules. I have a specific use case but I think that this question could help others in following some best practices when modeling real-world apps scenarios.

I want to model the following:

I have a collection of boxes in my DB, each one can contain N items which are connected to each other in a graph-like manner. Each item is only connected to the ones inside its box.
Users can interact with boxes through the following 3 routes:

1. `/boxes` => displays all boxes owned by a user, a user can add or delete a box
2. `/boxes/:id` => displays a specific box and what's inside. Users can only see the graph of the items inside the box
3. `/boxes/:id/edit` => authorized users can edit the content of the box, adding, removing, editing items and the connections between them (so they can edit the graph of the items). They can also delete the box and update some box properties (weight, size etc..)

I would like to separate these routes in 2 lazy-loaded angular modules, one with the list of the boxes (1) and one with the single box actions (2, 3) since the graph editing mode is very heavy and I don't want to load all the graph components and animations when a user navigates to the boxes list page.

Questions:

- how should I model the ngrx stores in my app given that some actions on a box are executable in both (1) and (2,3)? E.g.: I can update a box both from the boxes list and from the box detail (in the list I can create a new one giving it a name, in the /edit page I can change its name). In which module should the box state be stored? If I store it in the list page, when I change the properties from the edit page, I should update a store in another module (is that even possible/correct?). If I store it in the details pages, how can I display boxes properties when showing the list?
- what if I want to separate (2) and (3) in 2 different lazy loaded modules because I see the editing part is too heavy to load when a user simply wants to have a look at a box? Should I duplicate my store and have the same state and reducers only with different actions in 2 modules? Should I share the store? How? What about my components? Of course there will be a lot of components which need to be shared only between these 2 modules. Should I create a shared module that is not the "main" shared module that the Angular documentation suggests?